# 500 Internal server error when save proccess using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to ask why my codeigniter when add data become error 500 internal server when the save proccess. I dont know anything about this problem please help me all.

This is ajax code in view

```js
function save()
{
    $('#btnSave').text('menyimpan...'); //change button text
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
    var url;

    if(save_method == 'add') {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('edulibs/ajax_add')?>";
    } else {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('edulibs/ajax_update')?>";
    }

    // ajax adding data to database
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            {
                $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                reload_table();
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
                {
                    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                }
            }
            $('#btnSave').text('Simpan'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('menambahkan / update data error');
            $('#btnSave').text('Simpan'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

        }
    });
}
```

And this is my controller

```js
public function ajax_add()
    {
        $this->_validate();
        $data = array(
                'nama' => $this->input->post('nama'),
                'nim' => $this->input->post('nim'),
                'pembimbing1' => $this->input->post('pembimbing1'),
                'pembimbing2' => $this->input->post('pembimbing2'),
                'subyek' => $this->input->post('subyek'),
                'judul' => $this->input->post('judul'),
                'tanggal' => $this->input->post('tanggal'),
                'tautan' => $this->input->post('tautan'),

            );
        $insert = $this->edulibs->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }
```

Comment: Check your server's error logs.

Comment: I suppose the javascript is inside the php since you have the echoes. I would add a console.log(url); before the $.ajax to see the url that you are generating in php. If is is rigth then check the server's error log as previous comment said.

Comment: the error 500 is a server error. usually if you check what the server returns, (Ctrl+shift+i - > network -> red call -> response tab), you will probably see what's wrong with your server.

Comment: Use firebug in firefox to see the response of your ajax request. I mainly got 500 error with ajax when my database query is wrong. check your query and post it along with the question. Also, post the ajax response from firebug.

Comment: It say Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). firebug-lite.js:18994 POST http://pspi.upi.edu/e-resources/index.php/edulibs/ajax_add 500 (Internal Server Error) // send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 // ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 // save @ VM330 admin:199 // onclick @ admin:334

Comment: What's wrong with that logs?

Comment: @Whendikz add your HTML part too

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `site_url()` load `url` helper in your controller first.like this..

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

OR load helper in `application/config/autoload.php`

And in success function of your ajax use `JSON.parse()` to parse your json response into object.Like this

```
success: function(response)
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(response);//OR var data = eval(response);
            if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            {
                //code here
            }
            else
            {
                //code here
            }
```

Comment: I'm load url with this array code like this $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html'));
And i'm not use success function just save anyway

Comment: try to use `base_url()` in the place of `site_url()`

Comment: `console.log($('#form').serialize())` are you getting form data properly?

Comment: that's work properly, how to inspect other i dont understand?

Comment: right click then inspect element? and see on console tab